# Redmine + apache+ Passenger: Passenger still runs as nobody

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, redmine

I'm installing a new version of Redmine under Debian 8. I followed the steps described here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Debian_8_with_Apache2-Passenger

I had some problems with passenger so I installed it using:

```
gem install passenger
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

I added

```
PassengerDefaultUser www-data
```

on the passenger confing file and on the appache config file as well to avoid permission problems

The problem is that passenger is still running as `nobody`.

result of `top | grep "passenger"` gives 3 process named `PassengerAgent`, 2 of them runs as `root` and one runs as `nobody`. What should I do to have the effect of the configuration i added?

I have :

- Redmine version 3.3.0.stable
- Ruby version 2.1.5-p273 (2014-11-13)
- Rails version 4.2.6

Comment: Did you restart Apache to apply changes in configuration file?

Comment: Yes i did serval times

Comment: Did you check that PID of nginx and passenger processes were change after restart? Sometimes init.d or other the same initialization scripts doesn't work as expected and don't notify about problems.

Comment: Yes there is PID changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set www-data as owner for /config.ru file.